How to fetch topics using karafka
I need to do health check using karafka.
We have multiple services so for supporting this feature we have a separate repo rails-helper.
previously we used to do health check using kafka but there is requirement to update it to karafaka.
the kafka class we used to handle this
require_relative './base'

module Healthcheck
  module StandardChecks
    class Kafka < Base
      class Error < StandardError; end

      def self.check
        raise StandardError, 'Messaging system is not defined' unless defined? ::Kafka

        config = Healthcheck.configuration.kafka
        ::Kafka.new(config.seed_brokers, config.client_options.to_h).topics
      rescue StandardError => e
        handle_error e, "Can't establish connecection with messaging system"
      end
    end
  end
end

how we can implement a new class for karafka to support the scenario.
I have replicated the kafka class and created new karafka class. But i am not able to access the topics using this.
module Healthcheck
  module StandardChecks
    class Karafka < Base
      class Error < StandardError; end

      def self.check
        raise StandardError, 'Messaging system is not defined' unless defined? ::Karafka

        config = Healthcheck.configuration.karafka
        ::karafka.new(config.seed_brokers, config.client_options.to_h).topics
      rescue StandardError => e
        handle_error e, "Can't establish connecection with messaging system"
      end
    end
  end
end

For accessing this on service we use
config.add_check :messaging_system, -> { Healthcheck::StandardChecks::Karafka.check }

Karafka author here.
You can just use Karafka::Admin#cluster_info to do reachability as described here.
Please note that this is, in general, not enough to assess whether the Kafka cluster is stable or not. You may be able to do general reachability, though some of the topics partitions may be under-replicated, etc.
I am at the moment working on the health API, however it is not yet ready (ref: https://github.com/karafka/karafka-web/issues/416)

Is it the write way to fetch the topics.
config = Healthcheck.configuration.karafka
::karafka.new(config.seed_brokers, config.client_options.to_h).topics

Let me simplify my requiremet if we are fetching topics through kafka like below then how we can fetch the topics using karfka.
Kafka.new(config.seed_brokers, config.client_options.to_h).topics

Karafka has no syntax you provided. If you want to get topic list you should Karafka::Admin.cluster_info.topics
